# My debug version dll uses a release version of redistributable and crash

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010

I have a crash, only in debug, occurring in msvcr100.dll. I suspect a release/debug discrepancy. I don't understand why this dll as a dependency with release version of this redistributable (while the other dlls compiled the same way don't)

Here is the stack when program crashes

```
ntdll.dll!_RtlpWaitOnCriticalSection@8()               Unknown
ntdll.dll!_RtlEnterCriticalSection@4()      Unknown
msvcr100.dll!_lock_file(_iobuf * pf) Line 236       C
bard.dll!std::basic_filebuf<char,std::char_traits<char> >::_Lock() Line 310       C++
bard.dll!std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char> >::_Sentry_base::_Sentry_base(std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char> > & _Istr) Line 78            C++
bard.dll!std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char> >::sentry::sentry(std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char> > & _Istr, bool _Noskip) Line 99              C++
bard.dll!std::getline<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>
```

I compile with visual studio 2010, project uses poco 1.4.1

The debug version was working correctly previously, there was no unwanted dependency to msvcr100.dll. There have been heavy changes in the build process since and I don't really know where to look. What can cause this kind of issue ?

According to dependency wallker, the dependency is direct, and when I run the program in debug through it points to these functions:

```
GetProcAddress(0x75770000 [KERNEL32.DLL], "FlsAlloc") called from "MSVCR100.DLL" at address 0x71FABA3B and returned 0x75784EE3.
GetProcAddress(0x75770000 [KERNEL32.DLL], "FlsGetValue") called from "MSVCR100.DLL" at address 0x71FABA48 and returned 0x75781252.
GetProcAddress(0x75770000 [KERNEL32.DLL], "FlsSetValue") called from "MSVCR100.DLL" at address 0x71FABA55 and returned 0x757841C0.
GetProcAddress(0x75770000 [KERNEL32.DLL], "FlsFree") called from "MSVCR100.DLL" at address 0x71FABA62 and returned 0x7578354F.
```

And when looking the corresponding output of preprocessor I see:

```
#line 6193 "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SDKs\\Windows\\v7.0A\\include\\winbase.h"

[...]

__declspec(dllimport)
DWORD
__stdcall
FlsAlloc(
     PFLS_CALLBACK_FUNCTION lpCallback
    );

__declspec(dllimport)
PVOID
__stdcall
FlsGetValue(
     DWORD dwFlsIndex
    );

__declspec(dllimport)
BOOL
__stdcall
FlsSetValue(
         DWORD dwFlsIndex,
     PVOID lpFlsData
    );

__declspec(dllimport)
BOOL
__stdcall
FlsFree(
     DWORD dwFlsIndex
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio, go to `Property Pages-->C/C++-->Code Generation-->Runtime Library` and make sure it is "Multi-threaded Debug DLL" rather than "Multi-threaded DLL". Or, if you are building from command line, it should include /MDd rather than /MD flag.

Comment: Yes, and make sure you do this on the "Debug" configuration only. In my experience, it's easy to forget to set the proper configuration (usually Base instead of Debug or Release) when changing options, so when you change the configuration the build suddenly fails.

Comment: This setting is already on "Multi-threaded Debug DLL". Is there another way to get this issue, via a static import or something ?

Answer (score 0):

In case you are not aware, you can use the (excellent) software http://www.dependencywalker.com/ to find out what are the dependencies of a binary. You will easily see where is the debug coming from and will help you to find out what is wrong.

Comment: I agree it's a good tool and I already used it. My dll has a direct dependency with msvcr100.dll. I update the quetion with it.